# SwiftUI List Blink when appears List on the screen?

Tags: list, button, swiftui, navigationview, navigationlink

I have create two screen, first screen have a Button  and second screen having a List.

When I  click on **“EmployeDetail”** button  using `navigationLink` it will navigate on **List** Screen.

When it navigate first time list blink slightly. When I back on first screen and again navigate on the second screen so it will slightly move up side.

**I download demo source code from medium blogs,  over the demo also having same list  blinking Problem, A blinking happens on all the list screen in the Project.**

How can  I stop a blinking of list on the second screen. also add gif below.

```
struct Employe: View{

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: EmployeDetails()) {
                Text("EmployeeDetails")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Employee")
        }
    }
}
```

//List Implement In EmployeeDetails View

```
struct Employee {
  let name: String
  let type: String
  let indentity: Color
}


struct EmployeDetails: View {

        var employeList = [ Employee(name: "Vinay", type: "Permanent", indentity: .red),
                            Employee(name: "Ashu", type: "Temp", indentity: .blue),
                            Employee(name: "Vishwa", type: "Secure", indentity: .pink),
                            Employee(name: "Mia", type: "Ex", indentity: .orange)
    ]

        var body: some View {
          List(employeList, id: \.name) { employe in
            HStack {
              Text(employe.name)
                Text(employe.type).foregroundColor(employe.indentity)
            }
          }
        .navigationBarTitle("EmployeeDetails")
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of xcode you use ?

Comment: i just tried your code -> no blinking in 13.2/13.3

Comment: @Mac3n version of Xcode is `Version 11.3.1 (11C504)`  and `13.3.1`

Comment: Not reproduced with Xcode 11.4beta2 / iOS 13.4